# Angular 5 - Using the javascript google map api, registering eventhandlers

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I'm having this problem: I wanted to integrate the Google Maps Javascript API in an Angular 5 application. I don't want to use the Google Maps API component for Angular, because I want to extend this knowledge to other Javascript API's.

In the component, I wrote this code. In the addListener, I call the updateLocation method, and it works (I put a console.log() to check that it's called), but the UI is not refreshing.

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import {HostListener} from '@angular/core';

declare const google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})

export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  private punto:number;
  private puntoA;
  private puntoB;

  public sPuntoA: string;
  public sPuntoB: string;

  private map;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let puntoA;
    let puntoB;

    this.sPuntoA="Click para definir"
    this.sPuntoB="Click para definir"

    let mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-35.040790898800104, -64.70068372786045),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    this.puntoA = new google.maps.Marker();
    this.puntoA.setMap(this.map);
    this.puntoA.setLabel("A");

    this.puntoB = new google.maps.Marker();
    this.puntoB.setMap(this.map);
    this.puntoB.setLabel("B");


    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click',
      (e) => this.updateLocation(e)
    );

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }


  private updateLocation(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if(this.punto==1){
      this.sPuntoA = event.lat;
      this.sPuntoA = "puntooaaa";
      this.puntoA.setPosition(event.latLng);
    }
    if(this.punto==2){ /**/
      this.sPuntoB = event.lat;
      this.puntoB.setPosition(event.latLng);
    }
  }

  /* Called from the web interface. */
  setMarker(punto: number){
    this.punto = punto;
    console.log(this.punto);
    this.sPuntoB = "123";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ui not refreshing because only your variable updated not map. so you need to do following step.

you need to set map null first. so your code should be like

```
private updateLocation(event) {
    this.map.setMap(null);
        if(this.punto==1){
          this.puntoA.setLabel("puntooaaa");
          this.puntoA.setPosition(event.latLng);
          this.puntoA.setMap(this.map);
        }
        if(this.punto==2){ /**/
          this.sPuntoB = event.lat;
          this.puntoB.setPosition(event.latLng);
          this.puntoB.setMap(this.map);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution, i was reading about ngZone witch i understood it's like a manager of the "zones"/scopes/contexts of execution.

I just added the zone.run() in the code of the callback method.

Before:

```
  private updateLocation(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if(this.punto==1){
      this.sPuntoA = event.lat;
      this.sPuntoA = "puntooaaa";
      this.puntoA.setPosition(event.latLng);
    }
    if(this.punto==2){ /**/
      this.sPuntoB = event.lat;
      this.puntoB.setPosition(event.latLng);
    }
  }
```

After:

```
  private updateLocation(event) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
    if(this.punto==1){
      this.sPuntoA = event.lat;
      this.sPuntoA = "puntooaaa";
      this.puntoA.setPosition(event.latLng);
    }
    if(this.punto==2){ /**/
      this.sPuntoB = event.lat;
      this.puntoB.setPosition(event.latLng);
    }
   })
  }
```